# How to set background image for the entire scene in cocos2d xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working with cocos2D.I want to set the background image for the entire scene just I'm getting the image within the scene but it's not covering the  entire screen.can anyone provide me some information regarding this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use picture with size, equal to size of the screen(480x320 for non-retina iPhone/iPod, 960x640 for retina iPhone/iPod, 1024x768 for iPad, 2048x1536 for retina iPad). If you want to stretch picture to make it fill whole screen, change it's `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties:

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CGSize imageSize = image.contentSize;
imageSprite.scaleX = winSize.width / imageSize.width;
imageSprite.scaleY = winSize.height / imageSize.height;
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the background for cocos2d 3.x

```
CGSize wSize=[[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];
CGSize scrSize={640,1136};
CCSprite* background1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1136.png"];
background1.anchorPoint=ccp(0, 0);
background1.scaleX=wSize.width/scrSize.width;
background1.scaleY=wSize.height/scrSize.height;
[self addChild:background1];
```